# jQuery: Problem populating array when calling $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, couchdb

This is the code (refer to CODE) I use when I try to create new CouchDB document. The document contains one or more existing CouchDB documents (history tracking). The resulting json (refer to JSON) for the newly created doc is something like:

JSON:

`{

     "_id": "b3360050039389801524044daf1c963c",

     "_rev": "1-2a5da40ce9a191b4decc27411ec9a181",

     "hodoc_type": "INCOMMING DELIVERY NOTE",

     "user_from": "ANS USER",

     "status": "INSTALLED ON SITE",

     "category": "ASET",

     "location": "MTX SPARE",

     "doctype": "hodoc",

     "items": [

           {

                 "serial_number": "310310007590",

                 "status": "STORED IN WAREHOUSE",

                 "doctype": "data",

                 "supplier": "INTRACOM",

                 "po": "0",

                 "category": "SPARE PART",

                 "user_out": "IGOR JURUKOV",

                 "mac": "NULL",

                 "eqtype": "IDU",

                 "location": "MTX SPARE",

                 "location_comment": "NULL",

                 "date_in": "2011-05-06",

                 "date_out": "2011-05-06",

                 "prf": "0",

                 "part_number": "Z00-404/63.01",

                 "user_in": "KOTE JANAKIEVSKI",

                 "bar_code": "0",

                 "manufacturer": "INTRACOM",

                 "rma": "NULL",

                 "product_name": "PSU for IDR-SM"

           },

           {

                 "serial_number": "310407016955",

                 "status": "STORED IN WAREHOUSE",

                 "doctype": "data",

                 "supplier": "INTRACOM",

                 "po": "0",

                 "category": "SPARE PART",

                 "user_out": "IGOR JURUKOV",

                 "mac": "NULL",

                 "eqtype": "IDU",

                 "location": "MTX SPARE",

                 "location_comment": "NULL",

                 "date_in": "2011-05-06",

                 "date_out": "2011-05-06",

                 "prf": "0",

                 "part_number": "Z00-404/63.02",

                 "user_in": "KOTE JANAKIEVSKI",

                 "bar_code": "0",

                 "manufacturer": "INTRACOM",

                 "rma": "NULL",

                 "product_name": "PSU for IDR-SM"

           }

     ]

}`

CODE:

`var docids = new Array();

var items = new Array();

$('div#divitemsout').find('img.item-out-remove').each(function () {

  var id = $(this).attr('attrid');

  if (docids.indexOf(id) == -1) {

    docids.push(docid);

  }

  var item = new Object;

  $.getJSON('/whdb/' + id, function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

      if (key !== "_id" && key !== "_rev") {

        item[key] = val;

      }

    });

    // Check No.1

    //alert(item.manufacturer);

  });

  // Check No.2

  //alert(item.manufacturer);

  items.push(item);

  });`

The problem and the question are: When the line bellow Check No.2 is comented, the "items" part of the resulting json document is []. When the alert(item.manufacturer) bellow Check No.2 is uncommented, I get alerts with contents "undefined", but the "items" part of the resulting json document is properly set, just like show in the example. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just timing. The function you pass to `getJSON` isn't called until the web server returns a response to your request. So `item` will not be defined immediately after the call to `getJSON`. Adding the `alert` calls just slows things down so that the asynchronous call has time to complete.

Try moving the `items.push(item)` line inside the `getJSON` callback.

**Edit**

To make things clear, try this (in Chrome or Firefox with Firebug open, so that you have a proper `console.log` function):

```
var docids = new Array();
var items = new Array();
var waiting = 0;
$('div#divitemsout').find('img.item-out-remove').each(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('attrid');
  if (docids.indexOf(id) == -1) {
    docids.push(docid);
  }
  var item = new Object;
  waiting++;
  $.getJSON('/whdb/' + id, function(data) {
    waiting--;
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      if (key !== "_id" && key !== "_rev") {
        item[key] = val;
      }
    });
    items.push(item);
    if(waiting == 0) {
      console.log('items:', items);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry Gjorgji, I don't believe you. Are you waiting until your `getJSON` callback methods have fired before you log the contents of your `items` array?

Comment: I do not understand the question but there's one thing I must say.If I uncomment the alert in Check No.1, I get the correct value for item.manufacturer, and items is not populated as desired, no matter is it inside or outside getJSON code.If I uncomment the alert in Check No.2, I get "undefined" for item.manufacturer, and items is OK no matter is it inside or outside the getJSON code. I tried calling $.ajax(url, { async: false, ... } with the same usuccessful result.

Comment: @Gjorgji - you should get 'undefined' for `item.manufacturer` until the `getJSON` method is fired, which happens *after* the code you put at "Check No. 2" - that is, as I mentioned, just timing. You have two things called 'items' there - a variable in the code, and a field in the JSON document. Which one do you mean is sometimes correct? How do you know - e.g. are you using something like `console.log("items: ", items)`? Can you show your method for inspecting 'items'?

Comment: items is an array. Each item in the array is an object (item). I check the code execution via alert(item.manufacturer). The check can be also done via item.product_name, item.serial_number, etc. I also used $('div#somedivid').append(item.manufacturer + '<br>'); but the results were the same.

Comment: @Gjorgji: I edited my answer to show how to wait for all the asynchronous ajax calls to return, before printing the value of the items array.

Comment: The console shows the right values for the items array. The problem is that I write this array to the CouchDB document outside this whole function that starts with $('div#divitemsout').find('img.item-out-remove').each(function () {... I do it with doc.items = items. Now see my previous comments about alert giving "undefined" (Check No.2) as the only case when CouchDB document is properly constructed.So the real problem/question is why items is not corectly presented out of the above mentioned cycle? Except when I do alert in Check No2 :) Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @sje397: I modified the application in a way to dump $.getJSON block from the code. Many thanks for your efforts and patience. Still, the question remains :)

Comment: @Gjorgji - I still think the problem is just that you are not waiting long enough for the items aray to populate. `getJSON` is asynchronous, so the callback function doesn't execute immediately. Maybe you can write to CouchDB at the point where I write `console.log`, i.e. when the items array has finished populating?

Comment: @sje397: I was thinking of using jqXHR object as described here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/